# How can I add support for the `ToString` function in Entity Framework Core 7 for searching number contains in Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-7.0

I'm using Entity Framework Core 7 with Cosmos DB in my .NET application. I need to perform a search where I want to check if a numeric property contains a specific number. In order to achieve this, I need to convert the number to a string and then use the `Contains` function in the query. However, it seems that Entity Framework 7 does not have built-in support for the `ToString` function, which I can use to convert the number to a string.

I know that in Cosmos DB, there is a `ToString` function available that allows me to convert a number to a string. Is there a way to add support for this function in Entity Framework Core 7?

I have data like this:[image]

I want to search **ChargingSessionId** by Contains, ex: if I type **7** it will list out ChargingSessionId with id: **7, 17, 27,...**

I used Linq query like this:

```
query.Where(x => x.ChargingSessionId.ToString()!.Contains("7"));
```

And expect SQL will like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(ToString(c.ChargingSessionId), "7")
```

I have already tried using the `ToString` function directly in the LINQ query throws an exception.

[image]

Is there a workaround or a custom implementation that I can use to add support for the `ToString` function in Entity Framework Core 7 for my Cosmos DB queries? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You will likely have more chance of getting some kind of answer if you describe your scenario better. Tell what your data looks like and show us what kind of query you are trying to make. I've never had the urge to call `ToString` in a query; there's probably a better way to achieve what you want (as opposed to what you want to do)

Comment: Also, don't just say _"Using the ToString function directly in the LINQ query throws an exception."_, tell us the exception. Don't say _"does not work either."_, tell us how it doesn't work

Comment: What you want is not a simple and straightforward requirement (a number that contains a specific digit). Entity Framework is a generic ORM for a number a database types. It's impossible for them to offer and maintain all niche requirements. You will have to write some custom query for your database and execute that.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Entity Framework Core 7 with Cosmos DB in my .NET application as can be seen below code snippet.

**Below are the steps which I followed for the required output:**

- First, I connected my code to COSMOS DB by providing required credentials.
- Then created a Query Definition object by passing a respected query using contains.
- The Cosmos DB query's result set is iterated through using the while loop. The resultSet object is a FeedIterator that enables paginated retrieval of the query results.
- Then using feed iterator we get the result set object in a paginated way. The hasmoreresult set attribute ensures that the retrieval continues till there are any records matching the criteria is available.

**Below is the code snippet :**

```cs
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUri, PrimaryKey);

        // Getting the CosmosDB container and database name to retrieve records
        Database database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(DatabaseId);
        Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container = database.GetContainer(ContainerId);

        // Create a QueryDefinition object with the respected query using CONTAINS
        QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(ToString(c.ChargingSessionId), '2') OR CONTAINS(ToString(c.ChargingSessionId), '7')");
        FeedIterator<MyDataModel> queryResultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyDataModel>(queryDefinition);

        // List to store queried results
        List<MyDataModel> results = new List<MyDataModel>();
        while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<MyDataModel> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
            results.AddRange(currentResultSet);
        }

        foreach (MyDataModel item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"id: {item.id}, " +
                $"BatteryEndAt: {item.BatteryEndAt}, " +
                $"BatteryStartAt :{item.BatteryStartAt}, " +
                $"ChargedTime :{item.ChargedTime}, " +
                $"ChargingSessionId :{item.ChargingSessionId}, " +
                $"Cost: {item.Cost}, " +
                $"CostLimit: {item.CostLimit}"); // Modify the properties based on your data model
        }
    }
```

- Below is the item in COSMOS-DB:

[image]

- The result which I got in the console is in the screenshot below:

[image]